# Project with multiple Pipfiles

Tags: python, pipenv, pipfile

**My Project's structure :**

```
root  
|-Pipfile
|-main.py
|
|-first_plugin 
|    |-Pipfile
|    |-main.py
|-second_plugin 
|    |-Pipfile
|    |-main.py
```

The projects's `main.py` functionalities are to :

1. Run `git clone` in order to download each plugin from `Github`
2. Run `pipenv install` in order to install their dependencies
3. Execute the `run()` function from each of the plugins' `main.py`.

The `root/Pipfile` :

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
GitPython = ">=3.1"
PyYAML = ">=6.0"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

The `first_plugin/Pipfile` :

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
"-e ." = "*"
PyYAML = ">=6.0"
requests = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

The `first_plugin/main.py` :

```
from Plugins.plugin import Plugin
import requests


class FirstPlugin(Plugin):

    def run(self):
        if self.is_activated:
            print("The First Plugin is being run..")
        else:
            print("The First Plugin can not run because it is not activated")
```

The function `read_from_yml` downloads the plugins with `git clone` nad runs `pipenv install` in order to instrall their dependencies :

```
import yaml
import git
import os
import shutil
import subprocess as sp
import sys

"""
Reads plugins from a Yaml file and downloads them 
with git clone if there is not a subdirectory with their 
name in the Plugins directory


The format of the Yaml file must be as shown bellow:

    - It must contain a single list of dictionaries that must have the keys bellow :
    
        - name : The name of the plugin
        - url : a url of the git repo in which the plugin is stored
"""
def read_from_yml():
    #Open the yml file
    with open("plugins.yml", "r") as stream:
        try:
            plugins = yaml.safe_load(stream)

            #Get all the subdirectories of the Plugins directory
            PluginFolder = "Plugins/"
            possible_plugins = os.listdir(PluginFolder)

            for plugin in plugins:
                #if the plugin does not have a url, do nothing
                if plugin["url"] == '':
                    print("Not in the web")
                else:
                    #if the plugin has a url, try to remove the directory of the
                    # plugin from the Plugins directory. We do that in order to download the latest version of
                    # the plugin from the internet 
                    
                    try:
                        shutil.rmtree(PluginFolder + plugin["name"])
                    except OSError as e:
                        print("Error: %s - %s." % (e.filename, e.strerror))
                    
                    # Git clone the repository of the plugin into the Plugins directory
                    git.Repo.clone_from(plugin["url"], os.path.join(os.getcwd(), PluginFolder + plugin["name"]))

                    
                    all_files = os.listdir(PluginFolder + plugin["name"])

                    # Check if there is a requirements.txt file and install
                    # the dependencies it contains
                    if "Pipfile" in all_files:
                        os.chdir(os.getcwd() + "/" + PluginFolder + plugin["name"])
                        print(os.getcwd())
                        sp.check_call(["pipenv", "install"])
                        sp.check_call(["pipenv", "graph"])
                        new_cwd = os.getcwd().replace("/" + PluginFolder + plugin["name"], '')
                        os.chdir(new_cwd)
                        print(os.getcwd())

        except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
            print(exc)
```

**The problem :**

When I run the project with the cmd `python3 main.py` the plugins' dependencies are installed as expected. But when I use the cmd `pipenv run python3 main.py`, the plugins' dependencies are not installed and the program crashes at the first plugin with this error message :

```
File "Plugins/First_plugin/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

**Edit ;**

This cmd `sp.check_call(["pipenv", "graph"])` prints all the pacages downloaded by `pipenv`. I call it in the `First_plugin` dir and this is the result

```
PyYAML==6.0
requests==2.26.0
  - certifi [required: >=2017.4.17, installed: 2021.10.8]
  - charset-normalizer [required: ~=2.0.0, installed: 2.0.9]
  - idna [required: >=2.5,<4, installed: 3.3]
  - urllib3 [required: >=1.21.1,<1.27, installed: 1.26.7]
```

This means that the `requests` packages is installed. But the program still prints the previous error message afterwards :

```
File "Plugins/First_plugin/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Comment: Were you able to find a good solution for your problem?